# i want my x axis to display by increasing value

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Basically I'm able to graph the information I want just not with the format I'd prefer. I want my x axis to display its value in incremental order, not in the order they are read....the same way the y axis is displayed; in incremental order. Maybe it shows that way by default since it's the output value but I'd like to be the same for the x axis.... I've looked at the AxisOrientation API and have tried messing with it but nothing...any tips would help. thanks

```
 XSSFWorkbook my_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
 XSSFSheet my_worksheet = my_workbook.createSheet("example");
 XSSFRow row = my_worksheet.createRow(0);
   row.createCell(0).setCellValue(4);
   row.createCell(1).setCellValue(6);
   row = my_worksheet.createRow(1);
   row.createCell(0).setCellValue(2);
   row.createCell(1).setCellValue(10);
   row = my_worksheet.createRow(2);
   row.createCell(0).setCellValue(8);
   row.createCell(1).setCellValue(5);

   XSSFDrawing xlsx_drawing = my_worksheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
   XSSFClientAnchor anchor = xlsx_drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10, 20); 
   XSSFChart my_line_chart = xlsx_drawing.createChart(anchor);
   XSSFChartLegend legend = my_line_chart.getOrCreateLegend();
   legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.BOTTOM);
   LineChartData data = my_line_chart.getChartDataFactory().createLineChartData();

   ChartAxis bottomAxis = my_line_chart.getChartAxisFactory().createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
      // bottomAxis.setOrientation(AxisOrientation.MIN_MAX);
    ValueAxis leftAxis = my_line_chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
    leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

      ChartDataSource<Number> x = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(my_worksheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, 2, 0, 0));
      ChartDataSource<Number> y = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(my_worksheet, new CellRangeAddress(0, 2, 1, 1));
      data.addSeries(x, y);      
      my_line_chart.plot(data, new ChartAxis[] { bottomAxis, leftAxis });   

 // bottomAxis.setOrientation(AxisOrientation.MIN_MAX);
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, data points are connected in sequence by a the line if you choose to have it in.  If you just need data points, then I would recommend using an XY scatter plot and turn the line off when you are done.

Comment: I changed data to XSSFScatterChartData and it works however I only want the markers to show, not the whole line which is what I'm assuming you mean by "turn the line off" ...I'm looking at the api but I can't find such feature......

Comment: I only know excel.  My recommendation would be to record a macro, turn off the line.  Then review the macro for the change command and see if it rings any bells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JFreeChart is the best way to go in terms of creating charts..